# How to concat all the values of the nodes with same name

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

My input data is as below:

```
    <Data>
    <Sup_Offer  action='add'>80000001</Sup_Offer>
    <Sup_Offer  action='add'>80000002</Sup_Offer>
    <Sup_Offer  action='add'>80000003</Sup_Offer>
    </Data>
```

I am using the template below to check if node Sup_Offer exists and if it exists I need to concatenate the values.

```
    <xsl:template name="getDeactivateDataCmd">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="boolean(Sup_Offer)">
          <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Sup_Offer" >
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Sup_Offer,';')"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

As i am new to XML/XSLT can someone let me know: Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a little simpler to let template matching do more of the work.  The following stylesheet returns the string "80000001;80000002;80000003;" when handed your sample input, and the empty string when it handles a document containing a Data element that does not have any Sup_Offer children.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Sup_Offer"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Sup_Offer">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanq C.M.Sperberg it helped a lot. if i want to have output as text not delimited by ; but instead each value in one row what will be the change required

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Sup_Offer">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,';')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Data>
    <Sup_Offer  action='add'>80000001</Sup_Offer>
    <Sup_Offer  action='add'>80000002</Sup_Offer>
    <Sup_Offer  action='add'>80000003</Sup_Offer>
</Data>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
80000001;80000002;80000003;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitre. It served my purpose :-)